# Maven errors while building Trace Compass

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to build [Trace Compass](https://www.eclipse.org/tracecompass/) manually as described in the [README](https://git.eclipse.org/c/tracecompass/org.eclipse.tracecompass.git/about/) ("Compiling Manually"). However, I get a huge number of errors like the following:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.counters.core\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data @ 
[FATAL] Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.counters.core.tests\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data @ 
[FATAL] Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.counters.ui\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data @ 
[FATAL] Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.graph.core\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data @ 
[FATAL] Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.graph.core.tests\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data @ 
[FATAL] Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.lami.core\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data @ 
[FATAL] Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.lami.core.tests\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data @ 
[FATAL] Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.lami.ui\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data @ 
[FATAL] Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.graph.ui\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data @
.
.
.
.
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 104 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project  (D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.counters.core\.polyglot.build.properties) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.counters.core\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project  (D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.counters.core.tests\.polyglot.build.properties) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.counters.core.tests\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project  (D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.counters.ui\.polyglot.build.properties) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.counters.ui\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project  (D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.graph.core\.polyglot.build.properties) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.graph.core\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project  (D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.graph.core.tests\.polyglot.build.properties) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.graph.core.tests\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project  (D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.lami.core\.polyglot.build.properties) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.lami.core\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project  (D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.lami.core.tests\.polyglot.build.properties) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.lami.core.tests\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project  (D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.lami.ui\.polyglot.build.properties) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.lami.ui\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project  (D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.graph.ui\.polyglot.build.properties) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-readable POM D:\Scripts\tracecompass-master\analysis\org.eclipse.tracecompass.analysis.graph.ui\.polyglot.build.properties: input contained no data
```

I am on windows 10 with Maven 3.6.2, executing `>mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` in the root directory of the project. Where am I going wrong?

I have uploaded the [build log with debug option](https://www.dropbox.com/s/is1oo82g83mzxtf/buildlog_03122019.log?dl=0) (-X) enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The issue was that maven 3.6.2 broke polyglot (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6765). Using Maven 3.6.0 solved it.